# Describing computers as 'fast' or powerful'

Tags: english-to-japanese

When describing a computer as 'fast' or 'powerful' what are the right adjectives to use
Can I use these adjectives respectively, or do I have to use something else for computers?

> 強力な

> 速い

Comment: sundowner's answer nails it, but let me add a fun onomatopoeia - 「さくさく動くPC」 also works. Either katakana or hirgana may be used. And of course some call it パソコン instead of PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my ears, most idiomatic are 速いPC/コンピュータ(fast PC) or 強力なマシン(powerful machine). 強力なコンピュータ will be understood, but less idiomatic (or sounds like describing supercomputers).

Another possibility is ハイスペックな/高スペックな which implies machines with fast CPUs and larger RAM.